# When sending emails Mosaico logs massive errors about image files not found

Tags: error, mosaico, images, sendmail

I'm not sure why these errors are happening. They only occur once an email is sent to a group of recipients.

***ERROR***
message:            Failed to locate source file: https%3A%2F%2Fmensnet.net%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fcivicrm%2Fpersist%2Fcontribute%2Fimages%2Fuploads%2FUntitled_1_cb5b1defbb9800ae74ee24ce1560e094.png
code:
exception:          CRM_Mosaico_Graphics_Exception Object
(
[errorData:CRM_Core_Exception:private] => Array
(
[error_code] => 0
)